# package cannot be repair

Tags: package-management, netflix

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libnss3-nssdb: Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7) but 2:3.16.3-1ubuntu1 is installed
```

I am trying to do a repair, but it's cannot be, any idea? because i am following by http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/netflix-linux-html5-support-plugins

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with libnss3, libnss3-nssdb and libnss3-1d. I had installed some packages in the libnss3 family, but not all, and they appear to be interdependent on each other. In other words, I had some version mismatch and was stuck.

`apt` couldn't do anything because of unmet dependencies, so the guides suggesting ppa-purge, or downgrading from `apt-cache` using Synaptic (which I don't have installed) didn't help much. Some of the solutions I did find would mean that roughly 100 packages, including everything Java-related, every browser, almost everything related to GUI, would be removed.

Here's what I did in the end. **It might break your system even more, so proceed with caution and at your own risk!**

I found the correct packages (the version I had installed prior to the debacle) on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+search?text=libnss3), downloaded them, and installed the packages using

```
sudo dpkg -i <package>
```

Using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -f install` I confirmed that `apt` works as expected again.